# wordpress custom is_front_page logic

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I would like to apply my own logic in WordPress that'll determine if the current page is the front page or not and then I want `is_front_page()` to return that result. Is there anyway to hook into that function or use the 'pre_get_posts' action to change the necessary values so that `is_front_page()` is affected? `is_front_page()` needs to use my custom logic because I'm using other 3rd party plugins that uses that function and I don't want to modify those plugins so that when I update them in the future, my site won't break. Has someone needed to do this before and/or could show me what variables of the `WP_Query` object I need to change? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to "hook" into is_front_page(), you're going to have to create your own function and use that instead.

The function itself is very simple, I've included it for you below - use this as a starting point for something new and put it in your functions.php file.

```
public function is_front_page() {   
    // most likely case
    if ( 'posts' == get_option( 'show_on_front') && $this->is_home() )
        return true;
    elseif ( 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front') && get_option( 'page_on_front' ) && $this->is_page( get_option( 'page_on_front' ) ) )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: So I tried your idea Dontfeedthecode but it didn't work and crashed my WordPress instance, serving 500 internal server errors. Any other ideas?

Comment: @ChrisJohnson You can't just include the function I pasted, that is THE is_front_page_function I just pasted it in for reference - you need to make a new function with a new name, you can't have two functions with the same name loaded simultaneously or you will get a 500 error.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Sorry, I misunderstood your post. I thought you made changes to the function.